# splice/shift first n bytes of AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-iterator

reading the first n bytes of a byte stream (in form of a AsyncIterable) feels cumbersome and error prone.

Is there a better way to implement this?

```js
async function shift(
  length: number,
  stream: AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>
): Promise<[Uint8Array, AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>]> {
  const prefix = new Uint8Array(length);

  let offset = 0;

  const iterator = stream[Symbol.asyncIterator]();

  while (true) {
    const { done, value } = await iterator.next();

    if (done) {
      throw new Error("Buffer underflow");
    } else {
      const chunk = value;
      if (chunk.length < length - offset) {
        prefix.set(chunk, offset);
        offset += chunk.length;
      } else {
        const slice = chunk.slice(0, length - offset);
        prefix.set(slice, offset);

        return [prefix, prepend(chunk.slice(slice.length), stream)];
      }
    }
  }
}

async function* prepend(
  prefix: Uint8Array,
  stream: AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>
) {
  yield prefix;
  yield* stream;
}
```

Comment: If you're seeking code review, there's a dedicated SE site for that: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Otherwise, "_Is there a better way...?_" questions solicit opinion answers, so they're generally not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO.

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please don't cross post on Code Review. There is no reason to post there when you have 2 valid answers (and one accepted answer) here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**stream primitives**

We'll start by defining stream primitives -

```
flatten<T>(t: AsyncIterable<Iterable<T>>): AsyncIterable<T>
take<T>(t: AsyncIterable<T>, n: number): AsyncIterable<T>
skip<T>(t: AsyncIterable<T>, n: number): AsyncIterable<T>
toArray<T>(t: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<Array<T>>
```

```
async function *flatten<T>(t: AsyncIterable<Iterable<T>>): AsyncIterable<T> {
  for await (const a of t) {
    yield *a
  }
}

async function *take<T>(t: AsyncIterable<T>, n: number): AsyncIterable<T> {
  for await (const v of t) {
    if (n-- <= 0) return
    yield v 
  }
  if (n > 0) throw Error("buffer underflow")
}

async function *skip<T>(t: AsyncIterable<T>, n: number): AsyncIterable<T> {
  for await (const v of t) {
    if (n-- > 0) continue
    yield v
  }
  if (n > 0) throw Error("buffer underflow")
}

async function toArray<T>(t: AsyncIterable<T>): Promise<Array<T>> {
  const r = []
  for await (const v of t) r.push(v)
  return r
}
```

**shift**

Using these stream primitives, we can write `shift` in a comfortable and safe way -

```
shift(stream: AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>, count: number): Promise<[Uint8Array, AsyncIterable<number>]>
```

```
async function shift(stream: AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>, count: number) {
  return [
    new Uint8Array(await toArray(take(flatten(stream), count))),
    skip(flatten(stream), count)
  ] as const
}
```

Let's create a mock `buffer` and test it -

```
const buffer: AsyncIterable<Uint8Array> = {
  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    for (const v of [[0,1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9]]) {
      yield new Uint8Array(v)
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100))
    }
  }
}

async function main() {
  const [first, rest] = await shift(buffer, 4)
  console.log({
    first: Array.from(first),
    rest: await toArray(rest)
  })
}

main().then(console.log, console.error)
```

```js
{
  first: [0, 1, 2, 3],
  rest: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
}
```

**demo**

Run and verify the result on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ssl=7&ssc=68&pln=8&pc=29#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsICp4BtjLICmEAPACoB8AFMgFwwCC40AksQE7ABGuRp7Il178qlAJQNmkKIOF8KlGAG8AUDHjoOMYAHdgqZDGpRMII8Bjo4MZOJXqNMMKiK4AJjCzBHAX1X+qqAy8EhQaJheyMAA1qI09Ewsspw8ClQANDAQDBAIALbcQpJJMnJp8Q4acFo6+obGphDmMABuVjZ2VU6oNtQQALQDMKQAvDAADPYcRMgIHBCOGi5unu1+jr3GEDBKU7YAFhzoujAAohzHHNQARNwIcHBCMEjuQnC4JzfiAapByaEUBgdlgQDFUAAHRS0KTJcoiRRZHLZApFDglaRsVIIqjdGraPQGIwmMxGdrWWz2NROGBbfpDXaTexNNB5IhLZyuDxtDYaOk7Pb2ZBHE7nS5aW73R7PV7vT66b6-f4hRBAyLIdCMS7AMDQxKYlJCCqKEoABWO+VQIH4Wq4urE3SaLW04wA2gBdRz4upExqktodSkwDgAOghCBAB2orR+GhmcwWwaVwWggPCwJgkd6yGo5hmwHysLK2IUAFVUBBkAAOW06yhZUxIRJ5QrFbrx+Y7V0ciBEU7lys17VgaiEhoa2sj6JxagfAjECC55D5-LiBvoJviLdZDlgyGz-CEEhLldrmCNyuxmDunQgc+kpVOoxSp4cItYo0IgfVydKcbU28QiwV0AGUwEKdBcBDFNDS4DUOHdagqQ5b0SWaMlA1dV0JgyABGDIACZ3QyV0AGYMgAFmI10AFYMgANgyAB2DIq2ogBOd13WQmlli5Txe37Csf2HaMrxpMcjEEmBzXQS1rWoF0lGtZByFQfIiA3HMOCyXCJimcSYH8DR-ECGC0wiHZ8gMRcePvdCYFdOBUA4cwshmcwb3GSTMwObNqBfIQsgoq8nUgogQ0+ABzahlHgFzzCkYcQzgC1ZwSux3KIRKfXHTVRI8uxfB+QJrIrJCQ2FY8wr4SL0Ci9dmnCkMhCuH4gA)

Comment: Instead of defining these yourself, you may as well use the [iterator helper methods](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers)

Comment: I don't think your `shift` method works as the OP expects: it actually iterates the `stream` twice

Comment: thanks @Bergi I was unaware of the helper methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think the iterator logic itself can be simplified by using a [`notClosing` helper](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers/issues/71#issuecomment-576050602) and normal iteration:

```
async function shift(
  length: number,
  stream: AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>
): Promise<[Uint8Array, AsyncIterable<Uint8Array>]> {
  const prefix = new Uint8Array(length);
  const iter = stream[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
  let offset = 0;
  for await (const chunk of notClosing(iter)) {
    if (chunk.length < length - offset) {
      prefix.set(chunk, offset);
      offset += chunk.length;
    } else {
      const slice = chunk.slice(0, length - offset);
      prefix.set(slice, offset);
      return [prefix, prepend(chunk.slice(slice.length), iter)];
    }
  }
  throw new Error("Buffer underflow");
}
```

Unless you want to convert the stream from an iterator of chunks into a much less efficient iterator of individual bytes, there's nothing you can further simplify about the `offset` logic.

```
const AsyncIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(async function*(){}.prototype)) as AsyncIterator<any>;
function prepend<T>(val: T, iter: AsyncIterator<T>): AsyncIterable<T> & AsyncIterator<T> {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(AsyncIteratorPrototype), {
    first: true,
    next() {
      if (this.first) {
        const res = {done: false, value: val};
        val = undefined!; // GC
        this.first = false;
        return res;
      }
      return iter.next();
    },
    return: iter.return ? () => iter.return!() : undefined,
  });
}
function notClosing<T>(iter: AsyncIterator<T>): AsyncIterable<T> & AsyncIterator<T> {
  return Object.assign(Object.create(AsyncIteratorPrototype), {
    next: iter.next.bind(iter),
  });
}
```